# Find a root of a polynomial modulo 2^r

Tags: algorithm, math, algebra, polynomial-math

I have a polynomial P and I would like to find y such that P(y) = 0 modulo 2^r.

I have tried something along the lines of Hensel lifting, but I don't know if this could even work, because of the usual condition f'(y mod 2) != 0 mod 2 which is not usually true.

Is there a different algorithm available ? Or could a variation of Hensel lifting work ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a solution `a` such that `f(a) = 0 mod 2^p`.  To do a Hensel lift to obtain a solution `mod 2^(p+1)`, you end up needing to solve

```
f'(a)*t = -f(a)/2^(p+1) mod 2
```

for `t`.

If `f'(a) = 0 mod 2`, there are two possibilities:

if 2 does not divide `f(a)/2^(p+1)`, then there are no solutions `mod 2^(p+1)` (or any
higher power of 2) resulting from this value of `a`.

If 2 divides `f(a)/2^(p+1)`, then both 0 and 1 work as acceptable values of t, and you'll want to do a separate lift for each of them if you wish to find all solutions `mod 2^r`.

Note that `a` is in the range `[0,2^p)` at each step, so when you solve for `t`, you're evaluating `f(x)` and `f'(x)` at `x=a`, not `x=a mod 2`.